# Does mdfind allow wildcard searches on filename?

Tags: macos, search

I'm trying to figure out how to perform wildcard searches for filenames with mdfind on OsX? I tried: `mdfind -name "*.pdf"` but it didn't work.

EDIT: I want to be able to find names like "test*.pdf"

Comment: `mdfind` is such a pain to use! As an alternative, `locate` comes preinstalled, so if you sync the index (with `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`), you can use it instead, and avoid learning the `mdfind` syntax. Of course, the huge disadvantage is that you would need to sync manually. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/locate.updatedb.8.html
NB: Just to clarify: `locate` is not using Spotlight, but for Linux users would probably be more familiar.

Comment: Below is a pseudo locate that uses mdfind you can add to your bash initialization.
`function mdname () {
    if [ $1 = "-i" ]; then
        shift
        mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == '$@'c"
    else
        mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == $@"
    fi
}`  - the best of both worlds though messed up by the inability to add formatted code to comments so you'd need to add ;'s or new lines as in the original where those big gaps are.

Comment: @ccpizza Sadly the `locate` that ships with macOS runs as `nobody`, and can't search folders for which that user has no permissions to.  You can use homebrew to install GNU Locate, apparently.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887431/locate-command-cant-find-anything-inside-documents-folder-on-mac

Comment: can you just use 'ls *.pdf' from some sufficient directory?  the options on ls before filenames will determine your output.

Comment: Note that `locate` does not update its database with every filesystem change like spotlight/mdfind does.  It's typically updated once per week, I believe, so it might not be appropriate for some more immediate tasks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work:

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == test*.pdf"
```

Enclose the pattern in single quotes and add 'c' to match case-insensitively:

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == 'test*.pdf'c"
```

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161118160953/http://osxnotes.net/spotlight.html) is a list of available attributes. You can combine multiple attribute/value pairs with `&&`.

Comment: I could only get `mdfind` to work when the wildcard was at the start or end of the name.  So instead of `test*.pdf`, I had kludge it to `mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == 'test*' | grep pdf`.  (Even better, pipe to `grep \\.pdf$`.)  Sigh.

Comment: Oops, a missing double-quote in my preceding comment; for copypastability:
 `mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == 'test*'" | grep pdf`.

Comment: FWIW the * inside the name worked fine for me

Answer (score 6):

macOS ships with the regular `find` command, and `mdfind` is not a replacement for `find`.

If you really just want to search the current directory for all pdf files, you should probably just do `find . -name '*.pdf'`

By default `mdfind` searches by file content and metadata, and it searches your entire hard drive instead of just a single directory — on my system `mdfind pdf` finds tens of thousands of results.

If you must use mdfind, because it's faster, you have a few options to limit the results, for example:

```
mdfind pdf -onlyin .
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName = *.pdf' -onlyin .
mdfind 'kMDItemContentTypeTree = *.pdf' -onlyin .
```

Use `mdls` to learn what metadata is available for a file, and the syntax for pattern matching is very minimalist since it needs to match the database index of your filesystem.

Alternatively you can `mdfind` with `grep`, giving the speed of `mdfind` and full regex matching on the file path. For example:

```
mdfind pdf -onlyin . | grep 'pdf$'
```

One final caveat is `mdfind` does not search your actual file system, it only searches the spotlight database which may be missing parts of the filesystem or inaccurate. Use `find` if you require reliable results. Use `mdfind` when you require speed over accuracy and when you need complicated search terms (eg find all pdf files that were created within a specific date range and contain a phrase of text).

Answer (score 4):

When explicitly searching for file*names*, my experience is that the `kMDItemFSName` attribute provides more concise results. Another suggestion: add the `d` comparison modifier (insensitive to diacritical marks) to e.g. match a file called **"Entrée Menu.pdf"** when searching for **"entree"**:

`mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == "*entree*"cd'`

Also, since @tcmb's link to the attributes reference is dead, here are two working ones: [Spotlight Metadata Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreServices/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1) and [iCloud Metadata Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreServices/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Articles/iCloudAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011273-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself frequently wanting to use Spotlight to search for filenames by glob patterns, it might be worth it to wrap it into a script by saving this code into a `mdfindfile` on your path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# case-insensitive search for $1, maybe in dir $2
case "$#" in
    0) echo "usage: $(basename $0) PATTERN [DIR]"
       echo ""
       echo "  Lists paths of files matching PATTERN in DIR or below"
       ;;
    1) exec mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == '$1'c"
       ;;
    *) exec mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == '$1'c" -onlyin "$2"
       ;;
esac
```

Then you can just do `mdfindfile "*.pdf"` to search your machine or `mdfindfile "*.pdf" ~/Documents` to search below your Documents, or whatever.