# how can I find with mdfind a file which starts with DZ and ends with .zip

Tags: command-line, spotlight

I want to find out with `mdfind` where on my file system a file is located that starts with `DZ` and ends with `.zip`.

I tried

```
mdfind -name 'DZ*.zip'
```

but this does not return any results.

How can I ask `mdfind` to obey regexes or file globs?

Comment: mdfind requires a query.  I think you mean `find . -name 'DZ*.zip'`

Comment: @Gilby `mdfind`'s querys can be just a string term -- and the `-name` option restricts this string to filenames. I am certanly not interested in the slow `find` command.  However, after reading the [answer to the linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140791/15340) I understand that if this string is not of the format `"attribute == term"`, but just `term` then `mdfind` does _not_ do globing. (The other question has the right answer for me, so this one is a duplicate.)